# Set input value equal to object's property

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to set an input default value in Twig equals to an object's property. I've tried these:

```
{{ form_widget(form_confirmation.referee_number, {'value' : 'app.user.refereeNumber' })}}

{{ form_widget(form_confirmation.referee_number, {'value' : '{{app.user.refereeNumber}}' })}}

{{ form_widget(form_confirmation.referee_number, {'value' : {{app.user.refereeNumber}} })}}
```

But none of them work.

Comment: You should do this on server side, not on client side.

Comment: I'm using an if else statement, so I think it must be on client side.

Comment: What is your test is based on? Isn't this element available on the server side?

Comment: It's available, but the point is that if the property is defined, the input value is on readonly. But, if the property is not defined, you could set the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to write:

```
{{ form_widget(form_confirmation.referee_number, {'value' : app.user.refereeNumber })}}
```

Comment: Sergio, please put code format to your code part. Thanks.

Comment: @hokusai yes, sorry